# New Android device not showing on Eclipse's Debugger (Android Device Chooser)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

I just got a new Android device running version 5.0.2. I am trying to debug an app from Eclipse but the new device is not displayed in the Android Device Chooser.

I already enabled the developer mode and the USB debugging mode. My old device (which runs 4.2.1.) is shown perfectly.

On my device I can see the "USB debugging connected" and "Connected as media device" notifications.

From the DDMS I cannot see any device and nathing in the LogCat. When I connect the old device, I can see it immediately.

Any ideas?

Comment: try to restart adb, what is your OS, BTW your manifest excerpt is not going to help anyone from here, kindly post your logcat

Comment: Android 5.0.2. What is ADB?

Comment: what is your OS ? Not phone OS

Comment: My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: So you are not able to run any apps in your new device right ?

Comment: Do you get debug symbol(lollipop symbol) on top left corner on your phone when you connect it to your PC ?

Comment: Just updated my question to answer your questions.

Comment: Open command prompt and  type adb devices or type adb devices from your android-sdk\platform-tools directory, and tell me what is the output

Comment: I get "List of devices attached" and a blank line. I am using the same USB cable for the tests with the old and new device.

Comment: I think the drivers for your new device is not installed. So it is not able to find it. Google for your device drivers and try again

Comment: I installed the drivers and even hard-resetted the device. Still not working. Might the Eclipse version (Juno) influence? Or the plugins?

Comment: Nope, something very small is wrong with your phone maybe a setting.  Try in other computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it by following these steps:
http://blog.arturocalvo.com/2015/09/using-windows-and-cant-you-see-your.html